# React Router changes URL but doesn't update the page unless it was refresh from browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

So I watched a lot of tutorials on YouTube about React for beginners,
However, I was at this URL (localhost/) and clicked on the Settings button changes URL to (localhost/settings) and doesn't do automatically in the browser, If I refreshed the browser with the URL (localhost/settings), the page updated and rendered from Settings.js

Here is my code and JS if you mind helping me:
header.js

```
class Header extends Component {

    state = {
        MainMenuAppeared:false
    }

    MainMenuShow = () =>{
        this.setState({
            MainMenuAppeared: true
        })
    }

    MainMenuHide = () =>{
        this.setState({
            MainMenuAppeared: false
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Header">
              <header>
                  {this.state.MainMenuAppeared ? (
                    <div id="logo" onClick={this.MainMenuHide}><WebLogo /></div>
                  ) : (
                    <div id="logo" onClick={this.MainMenuShow}><WebLogo /></div>
                  )}

                {this.state.MainMenuAppeared ?(
                    <Router>
                <div id="MainMenu">
                    <Link to="/"><div className="MenuLists">Home</div></Link>
                    <Link to="/settings"><div className="MenuLists">Settings</div></Link>
                </div></Router>) : (<div></div>)}
              </header>
            </div>
          );
    }
}
```

Main.js (formerly App.js)

```
function Main() {
  return (
    <div className="Main">
      <Header />
      <br></br>
      <br></br>
      <br></br>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/settings" component={Settings}/>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Settings.js

```
function Settings() {
  return (
    <div className="Settings">
     Settings
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: don't wrap `Link` inside `Router`, your app should only have one `Router`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be single `Router` on top of the component tree. So just move your `Header` inside the `Router`

```
function Main() {
  return (
    <div className="Main">
      <Router>
        <Header />
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
     
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/settings" component={Settings}/>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and remove the 2nd `Router` from the `Header` itself:

```
class Header extends Component {
  state = {
    MainMenuAppeared: false
  };

  MainMenuShow = () => {
    this.setState({
      MainMenuAppeared: true
    });
  };

  MainMenuHide = () => {
    this.setState({
      MainMenuAppeared: false
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Header">
        <header>
          {this.state.MainMenuAppeared ? (
            <div id="logo" onClick={this.MainMenuHide}>
              <WebLogo />
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div id="logo" onClick={this.MainMenuShow}>
              <WebLogo />
            </div>
          )}

          {this.state.MainMenuAppeared && (
           
              <div id="MainMenu">
                <Link to="/">
                  <div className="MenuLists">Home</div>
                </Link>
                <Link to="/settings">
                  <div className="MenuLists">Settings</div>
                </Link>
              </div>
           
          )}
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the second method! I prefer this one

Answer (score 2):

Your `Header` component should be inside `Router` component.
Working [Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-poincare-wxj09)

```
<div className="Main">
  <Router>
    <Header />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/settings" component={Settings} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
</div>
```

Let me know if it works!!!

Comment: These are not methods, you have to understand, you can have only one `<Router/>` wrapper for the application, so we have to put `Router` component above `Header` component and removed from `Header` component as shown in codesandbox. Both answers did the same thing. I just had the second step inside codesandbox instead of writing it here.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution which worked for me . Give it a try if it works !!.

**Go to index.js file and replace ***React.StrictMode*** to
*BrowserRouter***

Attached the snippet for reference.

Good Luck [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMtZe.png)