# Link to not working while clicking but work when hit enter in url box

Tags: reactjs, react-router

[image]

When I click on Login or Signup In Navbar it is not showing my login and signup screen but when I enter url and press enter then it show my login and signup screen like this
I try everything. It is working fine befor but after placing in navbar which is using bootstrap Link to function is not working.
[image]

My App.js code

```
    import './App.css';
    import Heading from './component/Login';
    import Headings from './component/Signup';
    import {Route,Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
    import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
    
    
    function App() {
      return (<>
    
    
    
        <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/login' component={Heading} />
        <Route  path='/signup' component={Headings} />
       
        </Switch>
        </>
    
      )
    }
    function Navbar() {
      return (
        <div>
          <Link to="/login">Login </Link>
          <Link to="/signup">Signup </Link>
        </div>
      )
    }
    
    export default App;
    export {Navbar};


And my Index.js code is 
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App , { Navbar }  from './App'
import { BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import Axios from 'axios';


ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
 <App />
 </BrowserRouter>
 ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
 {Navbar()}
 </BrowserRouter>
 ,
  document.getElementById('login')



);
```

Comment: Why Navbar has been called as a function it should rather be called as a child component and why you are creating separate if for navBar?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Router changes URL but doesn't update the page unless it was refresh from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62509613/react-router-changes-url-but-doesnt-update-the-page-unless-it-was-refresh-from)

Answer (score 4):

there is no need to create another dom for Navbar,
you just put App and Navbar together.
like this ->

```js
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar />
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
    ,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```